# How to turn off the GC in Crystal and do memory management yourself, without any GC?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm evaluating the [Crystal programming language](https://crystal-lang.org/) for real-time, low-latency applications, that can't be interrupted by the garbage collector.

Two questions:

Is it possible to deallocate some class from the heap? For example, in the loop below:

```
while true
    p = Person.new
    # do stuff with p
    free p # <-------- HERE
end
```

Is there a flag like `-verbose:gc` in Java, that allows us to see everything the GC is doing?

Cheers!

Comment: You may be able to get by with surrounding "real time critical" sections with `GC.disable` maybe...

Answer (score 6):

You can free any heap allocated memory with `GC.free`. This is unsafe and potentially dangerous, which you surely are aware of.

Crystal uses [BDWGC](https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc), so you can use its [runtime configuration options](https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/blob/8faa9fc4e9c635457c84d68b9e5ecf8210572082/doc/README.environment) (such as `GC_PRINT_STATS`) to enable logging.

If you want, you can entirely disable the garbage collector by passing the `-Dgc_none` flag. But the entire standard library assumes to be used with garbage collection and does not do any manual memory management. So if you use stdlib, it will inevitably pile up heap memory.